# "L" characters showing up randomly in text in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm having this problem with [L characters showing up in IE 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hik1c.jpg). It's happening in the Healthcare Professionals block and the bottom two blocks. Any experience with this/clue as to what's wrong? I'm going to start deconstructing the whole page soon and rebuilding it line by line, but it would be great to get an answer as to what the heck the cause is.

Comment: Did you copy any of the text from a word processor like Microsoft Word, or OpenOffice?

Comment: That may be your issue. Put it in a cleaner, or just copy text into Notepad first, then copy and paste.

Comment: Looks like a _quote_ issue. Word and other apps use non-standard quotation characters which are not usually in the character set that most web pages use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can refer to this https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15709/strange-characters-appearing-on-websites-ascii-unicode

There may be some encoding issue with the content.

Comment: This is apparently an encoding issue, caused by more than one wrong conversion, and probably originally incorrect use of quotation marks. For a more exact analysis, a URL would be needed (a URL of a web page, not a screen shot).

Comment: There is - I was copying from Microsoft Word and Photoshop into a Drupal edit box, and the ASCII code `EOT` was showing up throughout and rendering as a superscripted 'L'. Copying the text into notepad++ showed the `EOT` chunks, and I could delete them there. Thanks!

Comment: I've recently seen this on a photoshop copy paste. It's not a a superscripted "L" though, it's actually printed as ASCII table character #192, which is the bottom left corner of a table.

Comment: In my editor (Visual Studio Code) I had to go to View > Show Control Characters and then I could see the EOT character that was showing up as an "L" shape.